# exc_badaccess error

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am trying to create a button that would call registration view that's under "View" group folder within the project like this:

```
- (void)signUp:(id)sender
{
    Registration *registration = [[Registration alloc]initWithNibName:@"Registration" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:registration.view];
}
```

Then in my registration view, I added a button that says "Back" to go back to my previous/main viewController.xib

But I am getting the memory error `exc_badaccess = code1` when I click on the "Back" button that does nothing/no action. I am using ARC. So I did not release or anything.

Comment: Can you debug and let us know exactly which line causes the error to be thrown?

Comment: Ok firstly do you know how to place breakpoints?. If so place a breakpoint some where initially then use "fn+F6 OR fn+F7", to step thru each line until you get to the line that crashes the app. If you are unaware of how to do these things, I suggest becoming more familiar with Xcode and your capabilities on how to debug first then try.

Comment: Breakpoint doesn't tell me anything - but I enabled the zombie object thing and this is what I got: 2012-09-25 21:58:04.718 Users[9745:c07] *** -[Registration performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x74710f0

Comment: Breakpoints are not meant to tell you any thing. If you look at you *.m files. On the left of a line of code if you left click the tiny pane area. It will place a breakpoint. Then you are able to run your app and it will then stop the program once it reaches the breakpoint and then you will be able to manually using the keys I mentioned above to move line by line, until the error is thrown then you will know exactly which line is the issue.

Comment: The thing is it won't go to my registration.m file. Once I the registration view is shown, and I click the "back" button, it doesn't call the Registration.m file at all. The 0x74710f0 is the "self" from but I didn't release it.. not sure why that view object is no longer there.

Comment: Sorry from what you have posted so far its like shooting in the dark. Please learn how to debug first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bet is that `Registration` instance is accessed after being released. You are creating `Registration` instance in `signup` method's local scope, so it is released after the method exits.

If my guess is right, you can solve this problem by persisting your `Registration` instance in ivar. Try something like follows.

```
@interface ...
...
    @property (nonatomic, strong) Registration * registration;
...
@end

@implementation
...
- (void)signUp:(id)sender
{
    self.registration = [[Registration alloc]initWithNibName:@"Registration" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:self.registration.view];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so  much Barley - that's it! How did you figure this out? So for my learning, every time a method exits, the local var/instance is released automatically using ARC? In order to solve that, it needs to be declared in the interface?

Comment: In principle yes, but it depends.

If your local variable is referenced with strong reference from another persistent variable, then your local variable is not deallocated.

Comment: What should I read up to understand this better? Like a term to search in google? strong vs. weak?

Comment: I recommend to read some tutorials along with [apple official document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html). Here is a good [tutorial site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1) I would recommend.

Comment: My problem now is how to go back to the main view. self.mainView = [[Registration alloc]initWithNibName:@"UsersViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:self.mainView.view];